# Get XML element value in Oracle DBMS_XMLDOM package

Tags: oracle, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I have XML file that's stored in the clob column of the table in DB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <row>
    <organization>asdklfjas;kldfj;LASKJFAS</organization>
    <phones>sjhdfhjaghjskfg</phones>
    <persons>hkjg</persons>
  </row>                                                  
</document>
```

I'm using `DBMS_XMLDOM` package for parse it.

```
declare
  v_clob clob;
  v_doc dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
begin
  ...
  v_doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(v_clob);
  v_domelement := dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement(v_doc);
  ...
end;
```

I need simply to get value from some element, for example `<persons>`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was searching:

```
...
v_doc := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(v_clob);
v_nodelist := dbms_xmldom.getelementsbytagname(v_doc, 'persons');
v_node := dbms_xmldom.getfirstchild(dbms_xmldom.item(v_nodelist, 0));
v_person := dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue(v_node);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the option to use XslProcessor functions together with XPath:

```
DECLARE
  v_Clob CLOB;
  v_Doc XmlDom.DomDocument;
  v_RootNode XmlDom.DomNode;
  v_Value VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  ...

  v_Doc := XmlDom.NewDomDocument(v_Clob);
  v_RootNode := XmlDom.MakeNode(XmlDom.GetDocumentElement(v_Doc));
  v_Value := XmlDom.GetNodeValue(
    XslProcessor.SelectSingleNode(v_RootNode, '/document/row[1]/persons/text()'));

  ...
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get XML Element value you can use either DBMS_XMLDOM or XslProcessor packages.
Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325936/2783908) to construct and DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument from CLOB column. Then use the below method to extract element value.

```
FUNCTION Get_Node_Value_From_Doc(
   v_Doc         IN DBMS_XMLDOM.DomDocument) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   v_Clob CLOB;
   v_RootNode DBMS_XMLDOM.DomNode;
   v_Value VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN       
   v_RootNode := DBMS_XMLDOM.MakeNode(XmlDom.GetDocumentElement(v_Doc));
   v_Value := DBMS_XMLDOM.GetNodeValue(XslProcessor.SelectSingleNode(v_RootNode,
   '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetLiveAnalysisIDSResponse[1]/AnalysisIDs[1]/guid[1]/text()'
   ,'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="https://www.testkid.net/"'));  
   RETURN v_Value;
END Get_Node_Value_From_Doc;
```

Providing correct namespace is important when dealing with SOAP XML messages.