# To change column datatype from clob to xmltype

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has around one thousand records in it and one of the column is of data type CLOB which now I has to convert to XMLType due to some other reasons.
How do i convert the column from CLOB to XMLType?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this:

1. Add a column having data type as XML Type in your table.
2. Copy the data of clob column to the newly added xmltype column.
3. Drop the clob column.
4. Rename the xmltype column to the name of your original column.

Something like this:

```
alter table yourtable
add (temp_col xmltype);

update yourtable
set temp_col = xmltype.createxml(clobCol);

alter table yourtable
drop column clobCol;

alter table yourtable
rename column temp_col to clobCol;
```

Comment: When I am copying data from clob column to xmltype column,then it is giving indefinite datatype error..update yourtable
set temp_col = clobCol;..with this query..

Comment: I am getting this error with xmltype.create(clobcol)...

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00216: invalid character 7 (0x7)
Error at line 3
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 5
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: Looks like one or several entries are not a wellformed XML. Verify with an external XML editor

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using DBMS_XMLPARSER package:

```
   -- Variables used for parsing the XML document
   xml_            CLOB := 'X';
   p               DBMS_XMLPARSER.parser;
   doc_            DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
   node_list_       DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNodeList;
   node_len_        NUMBER;

  -- Convert the CLOB into a XML-document enter code here
  P := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newparser();

  -- Parse the clob and get the XML-document
  DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseclob(p, xml_);

  -- Note that the document is parsed in local CSID even thought the xml       contains UTF8, strange but it seems to work
  doc_ := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getDocument(p);
  --- Bug 114812 SPM Start
  node_list_ := DBMS_XMLDOM.getElementsByTagName(doc_, 'NODETOEXTRACT');
  node_len_  := DBMS_XMLDOM.getLength(node_list_);
```

NOTE :-  xml_ variable should contain the message in CLOB format to parse it.         If the XML is in BLOB you could use this method to convert to CLOB

```
   -- Convert the BLOB-message into a CLOB
   DBMS_LOB.converttoclob(dest_lob => xml_,
                          src_blob => message_value_,
                          amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
                          dest_offset => l_dest_offsset_,
                          src_offset => l_src_offsset_,
                          blob_csid => 871,         -- 871 is UTF8
                          lang_context => l_lang_context_,
                          warning => l_warning_);
```